# Yu-Gi-Oh! Card Ruling for Keeper Of The Shrine scenarios

Tags: yu-gi-oh

Scenario:  [Keeper of the Shrine](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Keeper_of_the_Shrine) can be **special summoned** from the graveyard if a dragon is **sent** to the graveyard by **battle** or **card effect**.

- Excluding Tributes.

If my opponent has Keeper Of The Shrine in his graveyard, and I use a monster such as [Lava Golem](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Lava_Golem) or [Winged Dragon of Ra Sphere Mode](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/The_Winged_Dragon_of_Ra_-_Sphere_Mode) to **tribute** his monsters so that I can (as per the effect text) **normal** summon these cards, can he still special summon Keeper of the Shrine from his graveyard?

Although the card effect is that you can tribute monsters on your opponents side of the field, I can't figure out if this is labeled as "card effect" or a summoning condition and whether or not my opponent should be able to activate the special summon of Keeper of the Shrine.

Comment: no he cant, his monsters were **tributed** by the effect of lava golem/sphere mode

Answer (score 4):

Well, since the card [Keeper Of The Shrine](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Keeper_of_the_Shrine) excludes tributes, and [Lava Golem](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Lava_Golem) tributes an opponent's monster, Keeper of the Shrine should NOT summon since the effect of Lava Golem declares it as a tribute instead of a card effect.